# Java - How to center components horizontally, and stack them vertically?

Tags: java, swing, layout, components, layout-manager

I am writing a application that will take user information such as the name, email, password. To get the user information I am using JTextFields. I would like to have all the components in the center of the screen vertically and horizontally, and also have the components stack on top of each other one after the other like so: [Expected Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2erM.jpg)

Like you would see on a website. Currently I am using a JPanel inside a JFrame, the JPanel has a BoxLayout with a BoxLayout.Y_AXIS. Here is my code:

```
public class RegisterLayout extends Layout {

    @Override
    public void init() {
        this.setBackground(Utilities.babyBlueish);
        this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Register Now!"));
        this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    }

    @Override
    public void addComponents() {
        
        JTextField fName = new JTextField("Enter Your Full Name");
        fName = Utilities.designTextField(fName);
        
        JButton submit = new JButton("Submit");
        submit = Utilities.designButton(submit);
        submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                
            }
            
        });
        
        this.add(fName);
        this.add(submit);
    }

}
```

Both init() and addComponents() are called when the JPanel is added to the JFrame's content pane. "RegisterLayout extends Layout" and "Layout extends JPanel". Currently with the code I have my program looks like this: [Current Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuBsZ.png). As you can see the JTextField is off center with the screen horizontally and as a whole it is not centered vertically.

If anyone could help I would appreciate it. If you need further details please let me know.

Comment: Did you try vbox?

Comment: VBox has a parameter which will center its children. I think that is on by default.

Comment: @NomadMaker So I just tried, I removed the BoxLayout commenting it out. The text field then moves to the left and the button to the right and they are both still at the top of the screen but are centered horizontally. However I would like the button to be under the field and them to both be in the middle of the screen vertically and horizontally.

Comment: You're extending Layout, not any sort of Panel. Not that you should be extending JPanel, because it's easier to do through composition. You should put the button and the text field directly into a VBox, and it should work. You should not be extending Layout for this.

Comment: @NomadMaker "Layout" is an abstract class I made that extends jpanel. I am using this structure because it makes it easier to which between screen layouts "JPanel" using a layout handler which is another class that is handling which jpanel is being displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways this layout could be coded. This is one way.

Break the sections of the GUI into logical units, 'a column of text fields', 'an area for form controls' etc., then provide a container with a suitable layout for each.

[image]

In this GUI mock-up:

- The purple area has a border layout, with the two green areas appearing in the center and page end constraints.
- The first green area at the top would be a grid bag layout, to center (horizontally and vertically) the ..
- Single column grid layout of text fields, bordered in orange.
- The 2nd green bordered area could be another grid bag layout, or if only horizontal centering was needed, a flow layout.

Suitable borders (e.g. an empty border, which is invisible) could be applied to the containers for white space.

Comment: I will try this out and let you know how it goes.

Comment: So I added 3 new JPanels and changed the main panel "Purple" layout to a GridLayout(2, 1) "2 rows and 1 cols".  The first green panel's layout is a GridBagLayout. It holds the orange panel which is a GridLayout(4, 1). The orange panel contains the 4 textfields I am using. The last green panel is a FlowLayout. and it contains the submit button. My application is looking how I expected it to, thank you Andrew for the help.